# Declaring array and using it in two different Methods - C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, printf

I'm relatively new to C . I had a question can I declare an array globally and then change its value in one method and then use that changed value in some other method ?

like ,

```
int array[5] = {11,12,13,14,15}
void somemethod()
{
     //Changing Array Values 
}

void somemethod2()
{
   int k;
   for(k= 0; k<5;k++)
   printf ("New Value of Array %d" , array[k])
}
```

I'm asking this because I have done something similar to the above code, but the only problem is that when I want to print out the new values of the array , it just prints out values of `k` ,which is 0,1,2,3,4

Comment: Post the functional code.

Comment: "Something similar" didn't work? Apart from missing semicolons, this ought to work.

Comment: "when I want to print out the new values of the array , it just prints out values of k" How do you know it's the value of `k`, and not the values stored in the array? If the array has `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`, you'd get the same printout.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Here's the functional Code http://codepad.org/Eo7KTFY9

Comment: @fOcusWow; I am telling you again, your program invokes UB until you cahge `%d` to `%ld`.

Comment: @fOcusWow That's precisely what happens then - you assign `guestArray[i]` the value of `l`, which you `++`, so the array gets 0 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code - for which you've provided link to (http://codepad.org/Eo7KTFY9) is here:

```
for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS; t++);
pthread_join(guests[t], NULL);
```

That's just empty loop. In addition - second line accesses value which is not in your array since t equals NUM_THREADS at the time. It should be:

```
for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS; t++)
pthread_join(guests[t], NULL);
```

or even better:

```
for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS; t++)
{
    pthread_join(guests[t], NULL);
}
```

So in general your problem lies somewhere else and you ask the wrong question ;-)

In addition this is incorrect too:

```
void *guest(void *threadid)
{
    ...

    long tid;
    tid = (long)threadid;
```

tid will get pointer's value not what it points to. Moreover - are you sure pointers on your platform are the same length as long type? I doubt. Here is problem too:

```
long t;    
...
for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++)
{
    ...
    pthread_create(&guests[t], NULL, guest, (void *)t);
}
```

What you wanted to pass was pointer to t but casted to (void*) so you should have used:

```
pthread_create(&guests[t], NULL, guest, (void *)&t);
```

Likewise your tid assignment from guest routine should become:

```
tid = *((long*)threadid);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. I don't wanna wade through that code on pastebin though.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[5] = {11,12,13,14,15};

void some_other_method()
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("\nsome_other_method():\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("array[%d]: %d\n", i, array[i]);
    }
}

void some_method()
{
    array[0] = 420;
    some_other_method();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;

    // print global array
    printf("\noriginal array:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("array[%d]: %d\n", i, array[i]);
    }

    some_method();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So I see -- I expected it in `main`, to show the *global* array was changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define arr_len 5
int array[arr_len] = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15};

void change_array();
void print_array();

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    print_array();
    change_array();
    print_array();
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void change_array() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < arr_len) {
        array[i] = i;
        ++i;
    }
}

void print_array() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < arr_len) {
        printf("array[%d]: %d\n", i, array[i]);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
array[0]: 11
array[1]: 12
array[2]: 13
array[3]: 14
array[4]: 15
array[0]: 0
array[1]: 1
array[2]: 2
array[3]: 3
array[4]: 4
```